# Происхождение названий родственников

Tags: этимология

Сегодня, смотрю, вопросы по этимологии. Не буду открываться от коллектива.
Мне всегда были не понятны некоторые названия родственников. Например, с "прабабушкой" или "невесткой" все понятно, но что за слова "золовка", "свекровь", "деверь" или "зять"? Откуда они взялись в русском языке?

Comment: Juki, еще раз прошу Вас не изменять заголовки. Вы делаете это неправильно (например, ставите дефис вместо полиграфического тире, а то и допускаете грамматические ошибки). За формулировкой заголовков слежу я и, пожалуйста, предоставьте это мне. Ваши заголовки длинные и неудобочитаемые. Я много лет работаю в газете, и знаю, каким должен быть заголовок, чтобы он хорошо смотрелся и читался. 
Все еще не оставляю надежд на понимание.
Администратор.

Answer (score 4):

Ну система именований родства на Руси всегда была весьма причудливой и отличной от других. Связано было это с особенностями семейных и имущественных отношений. Подробности опускаю, это отдельная тема - и совершенно неподъёмная в формате форума. Что важно для понимания, в основу кладутся отношения одного супруга с родственниками другого. Девушка при замужестве оказывалась в семье жениха и для неё было необходимо различать степени *свойствА* (некровного родства) хотя бы основных членов семьи мужа. С другой строны для всех этих *свойственников* не было особой нужды в дополнительных званиях, все её звали одинаково, получалось, что девушка выходила замуж как бы за всю семью. Впоследствии это было перенесено и на родственников жены по отножению к мужу.

Происхождение каждого слова - это отдельный разговор, смотрите в этимологические словари. А значения я вам напишу, что вспомню.

- Невестка - жена по отношению к родственникам мужа, прежде всего - родителям и братьям-сестрам.
- Зять - муж по отношению к родственникам жены, прежде всего - родителям и братьям-сестрам.
- Сват - отец одного из супругов по отношению к родителям другого.
- Сватья (просторечно - сваха) - мать одного из супругов по отношению к родителям другого.
- СвAты (не путать со сватЫ) - сват и сватья, родители одного супруга по отношению к родителям другого.
- Сноха - жена сына по отношению к его отцу (реже - и к матери).
- Шурин - брат жены
- Деверь - брат мужа
- Свояченица - сестра жены
- Свояк - муж свояченицы
- Золовка - сестра мужа

Их было много больше, но остальные полностью вышли из употребления.
И ещё два кровных:

- Вуй - дядя по отцу
- Стрый - дядя по матери.

Кстати, вуйка и стрыйка - совсем не тётки, как можно было бы подумать, а жёны дядьёв. Правда это совсем уже забытые слова.

Comment: В большинстве случаев морфы настолько древние, что они, так сказать, сами от себя и происходят.
В лучшем случае иногда можно указать родственные слова (да и то под большим сомнением), но никак не предка. Вот свояк и сват восходят к разным ступеням "свой" и поэтому родственны. Остальные сохранили значения с праславянских, если не индоевропейских времён.

Comment: Если они очень древние, то должны иметь параллели в родственных языках. Ну, "матерь - mutter - mother" все нормально. С "отцом" похуже. "Pater" уж больше похоже на "батя". Заметна родственность в словах "сестра", "брат".  
Но с приведенными автором словами дело обстоит не так. Почему? Может, потому, что сами соответствующие степени родства перестали выделяться, поэтому исчезли и их обозначения? Или их и не было?   
Насколько я помню, в английском "mother-" и т.п. "in-law" имеет многообразные значения.

Comment: >mother-" и т.п. "in-law" имеет многообразные значения
Ну да, практически любая старшая родственница супруга.

Вы будете смеяться, но слово "отец" чтоль же древнее, как и все остальные для обознаяения близких родственников. Только означало в праиндоевропейском какого-то другого родственника, скорее всего даже родственницу. В древнеиндиском оно означает старшую тётку по матери. Фасмер преджполагает, что оно использовалось преимущественно вдетской речи (как сейчас "папа") и постепенно вытеснело "?pater" (не берусь утверждать, как конкретно оно звучало,  но какое-то слово было).

Comment: Что касается "батя", то родство с европейским "pater" отвергается. "Батя" ("бата") - исконное праслявянское слово с предположительным значением "близкий родственик, брат".

Comment: Насчет _батя_ я согласна, что-то об этом слышала. Поэтому и написала "скорее уж", а не просто "родственно". Меня больше заинтересовало отсутствие многих понятий в английском (других не знаю) языке. "in-law" - и все тут.  

Кстати, в современном татарском система обозначений в общем, похожа на современную русскую (без всяких деверей - шуринов), но, боюсь, что это общая тенденция, независимо от языка. Осталось только различение старших/младших братьев и сестер (старшие "приравниваются" к дядям и тетям). Соответственно, название чеховской пьесы переводится как "өч сеңел" - т.е. "Три сестрёнки"

Comment: Система именований упрощается вместе с самими семейными отношениями. В европах этот процесс шел быстрее, отсюда и простота названий. Во французском - аналогично английскому, только вместо "мама в законе" используется нечто наподобие "красивая мама" (молодцы, лягушатники!). Что-то похожее, кажется, в итальянском. В немецеком - чуть посложнее, но до русской разветвленности - ой как далеко. Старших-младших сестер различают многие яззыки. Венгерский, например.

Comment: Да, это так. Меня просто умилила театральная афиша.

Comment: В тексте ответа описка. Зять - муж по отношению к родственникам жены (а не мужа, как в тексте).

Comment: @М_Г  благодарю, исправил. Это очень старый тест, самая заря ресурса, с тех пор много подобных ляпов висит (технических проблем хватало), може править без проблем, если очевидно, что ошибка не намеренная.