# Кого можно называть родственниками?

Tags: этикет

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уместно ли в тексте называть родственниками, например, мужа тети и ее племянника? В смысле, тех, у кого нет кровного родства. И можно ли называть родственниками мужа и жену? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В современных реалиях вопрос изрядно запутан, родственниками называют всех, понятие свойствА и свойственника вытеснено куда-то на второй план, многие вообще не знают этих слов.

Начну с юридических моментов.
Вопреки yupaz, семейный кодекс и другие основополагающие документы считает мужа и жену родственниками, причем - ближайшими, наряду с родителями и детьми. 
вместе с тем в необходимых случаях (наследственное право, например) для исключения недоразумений список "родственников" оговаривается особо, но муж и жена входит туда в первую очередь. Но зато к родственникам без всяких оговорок причисляют и усыновителей/усыновленных по закону.

Во всех остальных случаях (и бытовом уровне тоже) обычно супругов причисляют к родственникам, если иное не оговорено особо. При этом обычно говорят родственники жены (мужа), противопоставляя их "кровным" родственникам, т.е. представления о том, что супруги - не совсем "родственники", где-то в подкорке еще сохранилось.

Существенным исключением является медицинские и генетико-биологические вопросы. Там супругов к родственникам не причисляют по понятным причинам, а для непосвященных тоже говорят о "кровном" родстве.

По церковным представлениям супруги (венчанные) - это лица, состоящие в духовном родстве - и в известной степени они противопоставляются родственникам кровным, каковыми признаются лица до третьей или четвертой степени родства (в зависимости от поколения). Однако в целом этот подход крайне противоречив, например приравнивает к родственникам супругов "дядьев" и теток. Эти вопросы всплывают обычно при определении допустимости венчания или крестного отцовства / материнства - между родственникам это недопустимо. Впрочем, об этом можно говорить много и отдельно, я не самый большой специалист.

Таким образом, даже опуская церковную, мы имеем как минимум три системы взглядов: юридическую, естественно-бытовую и медико-биологическую.

Но добавим сюда и историческую, она самая интересная, ибо дает некоторое представление о причинах нынешней неразберихи.

Начнем с того что брак воспринимался как прием в новую семью. Отсюда и обилие определений для родственников супруга - и минимальное для самих супругов по отношению к родственникам другого: невестка и зять - для всей семьи.
Полностью об этом - здесь.
[Происхождение названий родственников | Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3065)

В некоторых источниках (например [Свадебное торжество - Как называть новую родню | milinda.ru](http://www.milinda.ru/svadba/novaja-rodnja.html)) приводятся несколько другие таблицы, но я крепко сомневаюсь в их достоверности.

Таким образом, родственники по супругу рассматривались как родственники, но особого типа. Отсюда и происхождение слова свойственник, свойствО - от слова "свой". 
В отношении прямого возведения слова "свояк" - к свойственнику я бы воздержался, во всяком случае свояки - далеко не всякие родственники по супругам, напротив, это своего рода двоюродное родство (через два брака).

Стоит сказать, что в русском языке существует уникальная абсолютная система именования (кровных) родственников. Для любых двух лиц, состоящих в кровном родстве сущесвует термин, это родство характеризующее через разницу в поколениях и "расстояния" до общего предка: "пятиюродный дед" некого Имярекова, например, означает, что дед этого Имярекова был пятиюродным братом упомянутого деда.

Единственное исключение - двоюродного внука принято называть внучатым племянником (чему тоже есть исторические объяснения). Таким образом, все кровные родственники являются таковыми и с "точки зрения" русского языка.

Сюда же две важные вещи о названиях сожителей и "неполных" родственниках.
Очень часто используют совершенно неправильные термины, настолько, увы, часто, что это уже можно считать правилом.

Гражданский брак - никак не сожительство без штампа в паспорте. Гражданским назывался брак, противопоставляемый церковному. Т.е. как раз законные, но невенчанные супруги состоят в *гражданском* браке. Возвращаясь к юридическому пониманию, незарегистрированный брак там называется сожительством, но совсем не гражданским браком, а лица в нем состоящие - сожителями, и родственниками они не являются ни с каких представлений.

Сводные братья (сестры) - дети **разных** родителей (сравните из сказки: старикова дочь сводная сестра старухиной), родственниками они не являются. Совершенно неправильно называть так братьев по одному из родителей. Для них есть специальные термины:

```
Единокровный брат - по отцу,
Единоутробный брат - по матери.
```

Заметьте, что именно тут всплывает представление о **кровном** родстве, которое исторически считалось только по мужской линии. 
Забавно, что следы этого подхода рудиментарно сохранились в современном семейном кодексе, оперирующего именно этими понятиями.

*Уф... простите за опечатки, писал экспромтом, времени совсем нет проверять, позже вычитаю.*

> Вообще-то есть [кровные] родственники, а есть сводные.

Да. Брак людей **сводит**, не надо возводить к "сводне". Именно поэтому сводные братья - те, которые **сведены** браком, а не те, которые имеют только одного общего родителя.

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо за полный ответ. Он полностью соответствует моим представлениям по данному вопросу.

Comment: Так вроде не вы его задавили???

Comment: Но тем не менее =) Мне лично было б лень так подробно писать.

Comment: Да я сам иногда удивляюсь, с чего бы это меня на такие подвиги разбирает.

Comment: Думаю, с уменьшением числа детей в семье понятие "родственник" захватывает все более отдаленное родство и свойство. Во времена, когда у человека был десяток братьев и сестер, нужно ли было включать в ближний круг двоюродных-троюродных, по мужу, по жене? Этих бы запомнить! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Родственник - тот, кто находится в родстве с кем-либо.

Родство - связь между людьми, основанная на происхождении одного лица от другого (прямое родство), или разных лиц от общего предка, а также на брачных семейных отношениях.

Такие определения и у Ушакова, и у Ожеговой, и у Ефремовой. Получается, можно. Не зря говорят: кровные родственники, родственники по мужу.

Comment: Вообще-то есть [кровные] родственники, а есть сводные. Это качество родства, т.е. связь по крови. А есть еще родственники по мужу-жене. Это уже качество свойства (родственные слова - **свояк**, **свояченица**), т.е. родство через брачный союз.

Comment: >Вообще-то есть [кровные] родственники, а есть сводные. 
  
Вот это вы точно сказали. подробности в моем ответе.

Answer (score 4):

Если текст не имеет строго юридического назначения, то можно. Если же строго юридически, то эти лица находятся не в родстве, а в свойстве.

Answer (score 0):

в последнее время всех называют сводными и было наконец приятно получить исчерпывающий ответ.Дети-братья и сёстры могут быть сводными в единственном случае-если у них абсолютно разные родители,которые образовали союз уже имея своих собственных детей,а рождённые в последствии от этого брака дети,им уже будут приходиться единокровными по  отцу или единоутробными по матери. Спасибо за ответ