# Как назвать неродную сестру?

Tags: этикет, терминология

В продолжение темы родственников у меня еще вот, какой вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно называются сестра или брат, с которыми только один общий родитель? Насколько я знаю, "сводные" — это вообще неродные, а как быть в этом случае? В коневодстве есть понятия "полубрат" и "полусестра", а у людей как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так я ответил вроде.
Ну да, в той теме и ответил:.
[Кого можно называть родственниками?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19878)
(в конце текста моего ответа)

Единокровный брат (сестра) - по отцу.
Единоутробный брат (сестра) - по матери.

Это единственные абсолютно точные, если не официальные, термины.

К сожалению, эти слова сейчас крайне редко употребляются в правильном значении (особо понравилось услышанное у Райкина "единоутробная супружница", которое многими принято за чистую монету), но значат они именно это и никакой пренебрежительной окраски не несут.

Взамен часто используют термин "сводный", но это неправильно, как вы и сказали. 
Еще иногда употребляют "полукровка" (после Гарри Поттера, что ли???), но это совсем уж никуда не годится. Потому, что при таком употреблении не только неверно, но и даже унизительно.

Кстати...
http://kab00m.ru/projects/dic.html
http://rabbit-show.ru/rodstvennye-svyazi/
тут тоже не все бесспорно (ятров - разве это то же самое, что ятровка? может ятров**ь**?), но все ж для коллекции

//====

Я нашел приемлемый общий термин. Неполнородный брат (сестра) - единоутробный или единокровный. Меня смущало то, что в некоторых источниках к неполнородным причисляют и сводных, но все-таки, видимо, ошибочно. Так что "неполнородный" вполне приемлемо для рассматриваемого родства.

Comment: У Райкина *единоутробным* был папаша.

Comment: насчет папаши - что-то смутно вспоминаю, а супружницу, вроде, помню. Если это не ложная память.  

Вы знаете, интернет "единоутробному папаше (родителю)" приписывает другое родство. Про супружницу - действительно усомнился. Может, и, правда, не Райкин.
Черт его знает. Чаще всего встречается единоутробный муж... Бог знает, почему.

Comment: Похоже, вы правы. Нашел я этот текст, больно уж пересматривать весь фильм не хотелось.  
  
*...У мамы моей сундучок есть тонны на полторы. Вот тут мы его и поставим. Пусть на нем мама спит. Вот. Сейчас она у сестре. Поехала к сестры. Сейчас-то у сестре. От сестре приедет, прямо сюда на сундучок. Вот. Маму себе из Смоленской области выпишу. __А за ней и папашу единоутробного__, вот. Что я, по-вашему, своей папаше-мамаше борща тарелку не налью?...*  
  
("Волшебная сила искусства") 
http://kommunalka.colgate.edu/cfm/bilingual_view.cfm?ClipID=729&TourID=980&Format=fromFilms

Comment: Единственное, что в Интернете есть указания, что выражение "единоутробный муж" гораздо более древнее, ссылаются на дореволюционные источники, но бездоказательно - и совершенно разные.