# Существует (существовало) ли слово "умнёна" в действительности?

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы

Смущает правомерность существования слова "УМНЁНА" (название образовательного центра для детей в нашем городе). Если поставить его в один ряд со словами гулёна, сластёна, смирёна и принять во внимание значение суффикса, выделяющегося в именах существительных общего рода, которые обозначают лиц по их действиям и признакам, то такое слово "правильное", то есть, "имеет место быть". Но внутренняя интуиция противиться "правильности" этого слова. Существует (существовало) ли слово "УМНЁНА" в действительности? И тот же вопрос для слова "УМНЁХА" ( противопоставление для слова дурёха). Второй день вопрос мучает! Помогите с ответом!

Comment: Я не нашёл слово "умнёна" в словаре, но это не говорит о его "неправильности". Все слова когда-то не существовали. "Умнёна", конечно, выглядит непривычно, но тем не менее совершенно понятно и забавно.

Comment: О том и речь...

Comment: Подумала... Новые слова просто так не возникают. В них должна быть потребность. Они описывают что-то новое. Какай новый смысл (оттенок, эмоциональная нагрузка?..) в слове "УМНЁНА", который не передают слова, например, умничка и умняшка (они привычны на слух)?

Comment: Не разобравшись в теме, не надо ставить минусы!!!

Comment: Когда-то к слову "лётчик" была придумана пара - "льтица". Как видим -  не прижилось, хотя активно продвигалось энтузиастами. Осталось слово "лётчица". Предлагайте, господа, неологизмы - живой язык все расставит как положено.

Answer (score 2):

Умный - умнёна, такое словообразование возможно, и суффикс ЁН обозначает лиц по их действиям и признакам. Также  существует суффикс ОНЬ с тем же значением: тихий - тихоня.

В то же время сластена, гулёна, смирёна имеют дополнительный оценочный смысл, который к положительным характеристикам лица не относят, хотя и не очень порицают.

Возможно, именно это мешает принять новое слово как безусловно правильное и подходящее название для образовательного центра.

Comment: А что относительно слова "УМНЁХА"?

Comment: Нескладёха, побироха, завироха, растерёха - у этого суффикса явная негативная оценка, кроме  того, слова относятся к просторечной лексике. Второй вариант - стилистически сниженные синонимы существительных: дурёха, бабёха, правдёха, Катёха (без негативной оценки). В обоих случаях название подходящим не назовешь.

Comment: Вспомнилась еще тетёха (простореч. пренебр.).

Answer (score 0):

Слово вряд ли существовало даже в диалектах, отдаёт искусственным образованием за версту. Этот суффикс не предполагает семантики "наделенный (неделенная) чем-то". Если "умнёна" - от "умный", то "сластена" - должна быть от "сладкий". Вы назовете сладкоежку сладкой/сладким? Я - нет.

Answer (score 0):

### Грамма.ру

Слова "умнёха" и "умнёна" потенциально возможны, так как суффикс -ёх-(-ох-) как свойственная просторечию словообразовательная единица способен

образовывать имена существительные общего рода со значением лица, которое характеризуется признаком, названным мотивирующим прилагательным (ср. нескладёха и т.п.), а суффикс -ён- (-он-) - существительные общего рода, которые обозначают лиц по их действиям и признакам (смирёна и т.п.). Однако указание "потенциально возможны" и означает, что такие слова будут авторскими образованиями. Возможно, впрочем, что они зафиксированы в диалектах, однако том "Словаря русских народных говоров" на букву "у" еще не вышел из печати.

Comment: Грамма чего-то недопоняла. Смирёна - от смиряться, смирение. А умнена тогда от чего? Не по признакам это одразование, а по действиям.

Comment: Не надо оговаривать Грамму. Грамма права: эта просторечные суффиксы,  обозначающие лиц по их действиям и признакам (смирёна и т.п.). Смирена от смирный, а не от смирение. Ср.: тихоня. См.: Современный русский язык: В 3-х ч. Словообразование. Морфология. / Под ред. Н.М. Шанского, А.Н.
Тихонова. - М., 1981. - Ч. 2. - С. 96.Протченко И. Ф. Лексика и словообразование русского языка советской эпохи. - М., 1985. - С. 291.Русская грамматика. - М., 1980. - Т.1. - С. 157.
4

Comment: Серж, вы разберитесь сначала, потом начинайте вести разговоры про "оговариавть". Я ваших доводов не понимаю. Если бы разговор шел о "смироня" я бы вашего тихоню ппиняла. А так... Даже спорить не о чем. Смирёна - от смиряться, смирение. Слидите не за чужими идеями, а за мягкостью согласного, это в русском существенная штука.

Comment: Смирена от смирный, а не от смиряться. Неужели вы себя ставите умнее известных лингвистов!! Я привел вам издания, потрудитесь   заглянуть хоть в одно из них, а потом уже делать какие-то, ни на на чем не основанные, выводы!!!

Comment: Ен-(- онь) один и тот же суффикс.

Comment: Суффикс-то один, корни разные получаются. "Смир" перед гласным непереднего ряда в "смирь" сам по  себе не переходит. Неужели вы себя считаете "знаменитым лингвистом"?))) Я всего лишь хотела услышать как вы до таких выводов дошли, а вы сразу ругаться.

Comment: Вы не хотите понять, или мы друг друга не понимаем. Смирена от смирный. Здесь образование по признаку, а не по действию. Я же не из себя выдумываю. Я лишь цитирую учебники.

Comment: Тогда обясните, почему смирёна, а не смирона. Или покажите хотя бы, где такое "лингвисты" написали. Кроме "Граммы". Там нет **выдающихся** лингвистов, которые на вопросы отвечают.

Comment: Я же вам написал источники, где можно почитать. См. в предыдущих комментариях.Именно оттуда я взял. Сейчас поищу в интернете, может, найду.  А на Грамме отвечают кандидаты наук, доктора, профессора.

Comment: В “ Русской грамматике” приводятся отадъективные имёна с семантикой лица по
характерному признаку, образованные при помощи уникальных суффиксов: -ён(а): прост.
смирёна (смирный); -он(я): тихоня; –ёх(а): прост. нескладёха (нескладный)

Comment: [стр4](http://window.edu.ru/catalog/pdf2txt/150/56150/27113?p_page=2)

Comment: Смирена -Тот, кто имеет смирный кроткий нрав. (по Ефремовой). Если бы слово ''смирный'', как вы утверждаете, имело образование по действию, тогда значение было бы другое: тот, кто с чем-то смирился, свыкся.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже думаю, что однословного названия нет. В русской системе обозначений некровного родства совершенно не прослеживается стремления иметь отдельное наименование для отношений "через два брака". Это излишне. Это отношение трех семей, трех родов. Зачем оно? Есть, правда "свояки" - женатые на сестрах, но оно производно от свояченицы. Вот именно их, свояков, в народной речи в шутку называют "ятрами".

С ятровью - сложно. Историческое точное значение неизвестно. Поскольку "овь" здесь всего лишь суффикс женского рода (свекр - свекровь), историческое "ятрЪ" должно означать аналогичную мужскую "должность", но она не фиксируется. Ятры - свояки, как уже написала. Следовательно, можно предположить, что "ятровь" - это либо полная замена "невестки", либо, наоброт, всякая родственница со строны жены.

Comment: Это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос. Здесь вопрос об "умнёне".

Comment: Это, вроде, комментарий к ответу shampara про Ятрену. IrinaGL, на новом движке количество комментариев не ограничено, использовать поле ответа для это нет необходимости. Жаль содержательного комментария...

Comment: А вообще вопрос про ятровь где-то был. Помнится, я же на него и отвечал.

Comment: Да, это получилось на два вопроса. Первый был про сестру/жену шурина или деверя, которую тоже предлагалось назвать ятровью. Не могу уже найти его. А как теперь сделать комментарий из ответа?

Answer (score -2):

К **гулёне**, **сластёне**, **смирёне** для усиления красоты добавлю **ятрёна** - от ЯТРЫ  (жена брата мужа). От этого, конечно, доморощенная умнёна симпатичнее не становится: слышится корень МЯ (мякишь, мяч, мять, умять). Если не выдумывать слова, так лучше УМНИЦЫ не придумаешь. Вариант — РАЗУМНИЦА.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В принципе, первое, что пришло в голову при созерцании этого словотворчества на рекламной вывеске - "умнёна - гулёна". Произнося "умнёха", тут же хочется добавить "дурёха". "Шершавость" этих "умных" слов очевидна, но только не для владельцев фирмы. А жаль... Хотели, наверное, создать такое же удачное название как у интернет-магазина "Умнейка". "Факир был пьян и фокус не удался".

Comment: Жена брата мужа - невестка.

Comment: Кстати, было желание в заголовок вопроса вынести : "Кто умял умнёну?"

Comment: Жена брата мужа - невестка. Не фантазируйте. Где вы такое выкопали? http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3065  - вот почти полный список сохранившихся в употреблении терминов некровного родства. А "ятра" - мужские яички.

Comment: *Кстати, было желание в заголовок вопроса вынести : "Кто умял умнёну?"* - Кто бы Шампара "умял"))) С его-то фантазиями.

Comment: Вы меня, конечно, извините. Начали за здравие, а закончили за упокой. Просто наблюдение: почему-то в поисках правды почти любые обсуждения на безразлично каком форуме заканчиваются упоминанием репродуктивной системы и функций человека. Ха-ха.

Comment: ЯТРОВЬ — жен. ятрова, ятровка, ятровья, ятровица церк., ·стар. и зап., южн. жена деверя, зовут ее и невесткой, также жена шурина; | жена брата (деверю и золовке); | жены братьев между собою ятрови. | Ятровья, ·стар. свояченица. Толковый словарь Даля. В.И

Comment: НЕВЕСТКА — жена сына, брата, шурина. Другими словами, невестка — женщина по отношению к семье мужа: к его родителям (свёкру и свекрови) , его брату (деверю) , его сестре (золовке) и мужу последней (зятю) . Сноха для отца и матери мужа, ятровка для братьев и сестер мужа, она же является также невесткой для всей его семьи.

Comment: Ятровь - да, но не "ятра", ибо, как уже b-s сказал, это нечто другое.

Comment: Не так. У меня в тексте ЯТРЫ,  т.е. две женщины — ятрови друг дружке.

Comment: Нечто другое,  IrinaGL, тоже есть в словарике А.Ф. Папина из Происхождения славянской письменности — учебного пособия для для гимназий и вузов. М.: КомКнига. 2007. Шестью строками выше ЯТРЫ — ЯДРО (быстро, скоро).